# Check if dataframe row in colA, colB matches any row in colC, colD

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using PySpark. Working with only one dataframe. I want to flag if col1, col2 rows exist inside *some row* in col4,col5.

A illustration of the transformation is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGot5.jpg).

The focus columns here are column1, column2, and column4, column5.
Row 1 for column1, column2 have 0,0. This combination exists in column5, column6 so its True. We also have Null, Null 3 rows in a row which can be found in column5, column6 so its also True for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your csv name is `demo.csv` which contains 6 columns.

```
df = spark.read.csv('demo.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

You can create 2 different list which contains the combined values of `col1, col2` and `col4, col5` by iterating over rows with `collect()` function.

```
col1_col2 = []
col4_col5 = []
for ele in df.collect():
    col1_col2.append([ele[0], ele[1]])
    col4_col5.append([ele[3], ele[4]])
```

```
col1_col2
 >> [['0', '0'],
    ['2', '2'],
    ['1', '3'],
    ['null', 'null'],
    ['null', 'null'],
    ['null', 'null']]
```

```
col4_col5
 >> [['null', 'null'],
    ['null', 'null'],
    ['null', 'null'],
    ['1', '2'],
    ['0', '0'],
    ['1', '2']]
```

You can then check if the `col1_col2` value exist in `col4_col5`:

```
col_exist = []
for ele in col1_col2:
    if ele in col4_col5:
        col_exist.append("TRUE") #if exists
    else:
        col_exist.append("FALSE") #if not exists
```

```
col_exist
>> ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE']
```

As we can see, the we have found the required values of `Exist` column. Now we have merge this value with original df. Since new column with list values cannot be added directly in pyspark, you have to create pandas dataframe and merge those two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
pd_exist = pd.DataFrame(col_exist, columns=['Exist']) #contains TRUE/FALSE values
spark_df = pd.read_csv("demo.csv") #original df
spark_df['Exist'] = col_exist #adding Exist column
final_df = spark.createDataFrame(spark_df) #creating the final spark dataframe
final_df.show()
```